# Can Snort run on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: snort, raspberry-pi

I am in the preliminary stages of designing a cybersecurity suite for my home network. I don't have any servers or anything, just the standard home setup (computers, tablets, game consoles). The bandwidth on my service plan is about 25-35Mbps and I really don't think I'm even using more than 50% of that at peak usage.

I want to setup Snort IDS on a small discrete device. I have a Raspberry Pi Zero W but that may be pushing it regarding system resources. Would a Pi 3 work? Does anyone have any experience with a similar setup?

I plan to use it in a network tap layout and I don't want to use a dedicated PC for just that one role. The usual setup for these is to have it as a VM but if I use a PC for multiple VMs, that leaves a single point of failure which I'd prefer to avoid, if I can.

So, can a Raspberry Pi (any version) run Snort without issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, can a Raspberry Pi (any version) run Snort without issue?

No. Simply put the Pi (any of them) does not have enough RAM and CPU to make it work. It will simply not keep up.

And in case you ask. If you wanted to set it up to do the best it can and ignore any traffic it can't keep up with then don't do that. It's pointless monitoring some of your traffic and not all.

Comment: It seems from the response from Khurt Williams that it is possible and has been done before more than once? Have you tried this and it failed? If so, can you include more details so people know what to avoid (like using Kali instead of RaspbianLite? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can. Here's how:

See section: "HOW TO INSTALL SNORT ON A RASPBERRY PI"

> Follow some of the recommended best practices for expanding the memory space on your SD card once Raspbian is installed.

https://blog.holdenkilbride.com/index.php/2016/10/25/turn-your-raspberry-pi-into-a-snort-ids/

and another solution that uses Kali Linux as a starting point:

https://www.securityforrealpeople.com/2014/09/installing-kali-linux-and-snort-on.html

Comment: please do not just post links, include the relevant parts of the links in your answer

Comment: These links still lack context. Your quote does not lead to anywhere in the referenced article. *How* do you expand the memory? That point is what will differentiate this answer from the others and provide a way forward.

Answer (score 4):

Simple answer is no. Snort, at a min, requires 1-2GB of RAM and even then it can struggle. It would be difficult to get it to run efficiently on a Pi3 and very very difficult, if not impossible on a pi zero. I would not recommend using a Pi as an IDS/IPS system.

So what can you do? Well, if you have any older computers gathering dust, you can certainly configure one of those to run Snort or even look into Security Onion which is a Linux distribution with a suite of IDS tools including Bro which is very powerful. Also, look into PFsense which, can configure snort within it and act a network router, etc.etc. and so much more.

Don't have any computers gathering dust? You might be able to get by on an Intel Atom SBC. There are a ton of options but, the solution is more processing power and more RAM. Also a 1Gb NIC is preferable and the Pi 3 does not have that.

Okay, that's all fun but, what can you do with your pi? Well, I would honestly [set-up Pi-hole](https://pi-hole.net/) if you haven't already.

Comment: does this still hold with raspberry pi 4 (with 4GB of ram)?

Answer (score 2):

I am using a Raspberry Pi 4, and cannot find Snort within any of the repositories as they do not support ARM architecture. 
`sudo apt-get install snort` works fine on a virtualized environment but not on the Pi.

```
E: unable to locate package snort
```

Not sure if it's some of the repositories or if it's snort, or possibly a bit of both that doesn't play ball with the arm architecture, either way I'm going to have to use a different OS and/or software to create an IDS on a Pi 4. There are lots of documentation but they don't encounter this issue cause they haven't used a Pi processor.

Ubuntu Sec onion would work but I know from exp. that Sec onion needs more than 4GB RAM to run well.

Comment: It seems to work on my Raspbian: `/home/pi 20-07-09 4:14 $ apt-cache show snort
Package: snort
Version: 2.9.7.0-5
Architecture: armhf`